# async await in UWP windows 10 IOT core running in Raspberry Pi 3B and memory leak

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

First of all I am a complete begineer in C# and literally don't know how to use async/await/cancellation/Tasks, I come from a embedded systems background with basic-moderate C/C++ knowledge. So i just get the idea what those async functions do here. the async task codes are copied from samples from microsoft, they simply keep on reading the serial port for new bytes. I made some animations for the UI through Blend, and that's just it nothing more fancy.

This app runs on a raspberry with IOT core, and its sole job is to provide a UI for user to control a microcontroller with plain text instructions send through serial port. All these buttons simply send some strings to serial port which my microcontroller reads and acts accordingly.

Problem 1: I modified a line in the ReadAsync function `uint ReadBufferLength = 1;` the value was 128 in sample code, my microcontroller sends a complete instruction or data ending with "\r\n". This meant it will keep on reading bytes in serial that come from the microcontroller until the buffer is full and call the ReadAsync function again. since it was reading until the buffer (128) was full, multiple instructions come and fill the buffer. So i had no way to figure out what is the instruction in the buffer. So my work around here was to change the buffer to 1 and append a string with new bytes from serial port until it finds `Environment.NewLine` and then build logic based on the complete instruction in the string.

Question 1: How do I modify the code to not change the `uint ReadBufferLength = 1;` and make the ReadAsync function store my serial incoming data until it finds \r\n ?

**MAJOR** Problem 2: As soon as I enter Manual/Auto mode by clicking the front panel button, my microcontroller starts sending temperature sensor value through serial port as fast as possible without any delay between instructions. I know the raspberry pi (win10 iot core) is fast enough to not miss any instruction or the physical serial port buffer of the PI getting overfilled. It works fine, there is no problem at this point in the app, no crash or slowdowns. But overtime I can see that the app is consuming more and more RAM. the behavior is same in PC if I build it in x86 mode. after running it for 1 hour it will consume over 120 megabytes whereas it starts at 30-50 megabytes initially.

To recreate the problem, please change `string qFilter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");` UART0 to appropriate com port in windows. otherwise the app will not run. Probably a Virtual COM port needs to be installed or a usb to ttl module might be required.

Problem 3: Cannot build the app in release mode using the option "Compile with .NET Native tool chain", without this it runs fine in the raspberry.

`Internal compiler error: MCG0024:UnresolvableTypeReference Unresolvable type reference 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IRestrictedErrorInfo' in 'Assembly(Name=System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type. hvac_version_4`  
[github project file](https://github.com/rvxfahim/hvac_version_2)

```
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.Threading;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations.Behaviors;
// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace hvac_version_2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        SolidColorBrush greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        SolidColorBrush greyBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateGray);

        //private bool updatingValues;


        private CancellationTokenSource ReadCancellationTokenSource;
        private SerialDevice serialPort = null;
        DataWriter dataWriteObject = null;
        DataReader dataReaderObject = null;
        public string strFromPort;
        private string final_string;
        
        private int compressorAkey=0;
        private int compressorBkey=0;
        private int pump_entry = 0;
        private int compAentry=0;
        private int compBentry=0;
        private int fan1entry = 0;
        private int fan2entry = 0;
        private double Blur_amount = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            stop_button.IsEnabled = false;
            set_temperature.IsEnabled = false;
            set_switching_time.IsEnabled = false;
            auto_mode.IsEnabled = false;
            manual_mode.IsEnabled = false;
            compressorA_button.IsEnabled = false;
            compressorB_button.IsEnabled = false;
            fanA_button.IsEnabled = false;
            fanB_button.IsEnabled = false;
            init.IsEnabled = false;
            init_timing.IsEnabled = false;
            pump_button.IsEnabled = false;
            load_animation.Begin();
            
        }

        private async void stop_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do something
            start_animation.Stop();
            if (serialPort == null) return;
            await sendToPort("end");
            set_temperature.IsEnabled = false;
            set_switching_time.IsEnabled = false;
            manual_mode.IsEnabled = true;
            auto_mode.IsEnabled = true;
            stop_button.IsEnabled = false;
            compressorA_button.IsEnabled = false;
            compressorB_button.IsEnabled = false;
            fanA_button.IsEnabled = false;
            fanB_button.IsEnabled = false;
            init.IsEnabled = false;
            init_timing.IsEnabled = false;
            pump_button.IsEnabled = false;
            start_button.IsEnabled = true;
            pump_entry = 0;
            compAentry = 0;
            compBentry = 0;
            fan1entry = 0;
            fan2entry = 0;
            stop_animation.Begin();
            start_button.Width = 162;
            GC.Collect();
        }

        
        
        private async void set_temperature_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("entered the async void set_temp.............");
            
            
        }

        private async void set_switching_time_value_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("entered the async void switching time.............");
            
            

        }

        private async void manual_mode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort == null) return;
            await sendToPort("manual");
            auto_mode.IsEnabled = false;
            manual_mode.IsEnabled = false;
            stop_button.IsEnabled = true;
            set_temperature.IsEnabled = true;
            set_switching_time.IsEnabled = true;
            pump_button.IsEnabled = true;
            fanA_button.IsEnabled = true;
            fanB_button.IsEnabled = true;
            compressorA_button.IsEnabled = true;
            compressorB_button.IsEnabled = true;
            init.IsEnabled = true;
            init_timing.IsEnabled = true;
            
        }

        private async void auto_mode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            set_switching_time.IsEnabled = true;
            set_temperature.IsEnabled = true;
            init.IsEnabled = true;
            stop_button.IsEnabled = true;
            init_timing.IsEnabled = true;
            if (serialPort == null) return;
            await sendToPort("auto");

        }

        private async void start_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            stop_animation.Stop();
            await sendToPort("ready");
            auto_mode.IsEnabled = true;
            manual_mode.IsEnabled = true;
            start_button.IsEnabled = false;
            start_animation.Begin();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sending ready command");
            
            
        }

        private async void compressorA_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (compAentry == 0)
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("compressorAON");   //sending key
                compAentry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("compressorAoff");  //sending key
                compAentry = 0;
            }
        }

        private async void compressorB_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (compBentry == 0)
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("compressorBON");   //sending key
                compBentry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("compressorBoff");  //sending key
                compBentry = 0;
            }
        }

        private async void fanA_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (fan1entry == 0)
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("fan1on"); 
                fan1entry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("fan1off");  
                fan1entry = 0;
            }
        }

        private async void fanB_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (fan2entry == 0)
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("fan2on");
                fan2entry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("fan2off");
                fan2entry = 0;
            }
        }

        private async void pump_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pump_entry == 0)
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("pumpon");
                pump_entry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (serialPort == null) return;
                await sendToPort("pumpoff");
                pump_entry = 0;
            }

        }

        private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string qFilter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");
            DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(qFilter);

            if (devices.Any())
            {
                string deviceId = devices.First().Id;

                 await OpenPort(deviceId);
            }

            ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            while (true)
            {
                
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("program came before await listen");
                await Listen();
            }
        }


        
        private async Task OpenPort(string deviceId)
        {
            serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
                serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
                serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
                //Console.WriteLine("Serial port configured successfully");
                //txtStatus.Text = "Serial port configured successfully";
                

            }
        }

        
        private async Task Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort != null)
                {
                    dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
                    await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dataReaderObject != null)    // Cleanup once complete
                {
                    dataReaderObject.DetachStream();
                    dataReaderObject = null;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

            uint ReadBufferLength = 1;  // only when this buffer would be full next code would be executed

            dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

            loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);   // Create a task object
            //string debug = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead2);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("writing string debug"+ debug);

            UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;    // Launch the task and wait until buffer would be full

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                strFromPort = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
                final_string = final_string + strFromPort;
                //txtStatus2.Text = final_string;
                if (final_string.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
                {
                    string logicstring = final_string;
                    final_string = "";

                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("writing logic string " + logicstring);
                    
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("A"))
                    {   
                        if(logicstring.Contains("-"))
                        {
                            //it is a negative number
                            logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                            int gauge1_pass = int.Parse(logicstring) * -1;
                            tempgauge1.Value = gauge1_pass;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                            int gauge1_pass = int.Parse(logicstring);
                            tempgauge1.Value = gauge1_pass;
                        }
                    }



                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("B"))
                    {
                        if (logicstring.Contains("-"))
                        {
                            //it is a negative number
                            logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                            int gauge2_pass = int.Parse(logicstring) * -1;
                            tempgauge1.Value = gauge2_pass;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                            int gauge2_pass = int.Parse(logicstring);
                            tempgauge2.Value = gauge2_pass;
                        }
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("setting"))
                    {
                        if (logicstring.Contains("-"))
                        {
                            //it is a negative number
                            logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                            int previous_temp_setting = int.Parse(logicstring) * -1;
                            set_temperature.Value = previous_temp_setting;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                            int previous_temp_setting = int.Parse(logicstring);
                            set_temperature.Value = previous_temp_setting;
                        }
                    }

                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("pumpon"))
                    {
                        pump_status_light.Fill = greenBrush;
                        Storyboard_Pump_Led.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                        Storyboard_Pump_Led.Begin();

                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("pumpoff"))
                    {   
                        pump_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                        Storyboard_Pump_Led.Stop();
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("pumpfail"))
                    {
                        if (!FailPopup.IsOpen) 
                        { 
                            FailPopup.IsOpen = true; 
                        }
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("clear the popup"))
                    {
                        if (FailPopup.IsOpen) 
                        {
                            FailPopup.IsOpen = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("switch_interval"))
                    {
                        
                            
                            logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                            int previous_interval_setting = int.Parse(logicstring);
                            set_switching_time.Value = previous_interval_setting;


                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("timer"))
                    {


                        logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                        int remaining_time = int.Parse(logicstring);
                        remaining_time = remaining_time / 1000;
                        timer_box.Text = remaining_time.ToString();


                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("Free RAM = "))
                    {


                        logicstring = Regex.Match(logicstring, @"\d+").Value;
                        int remaining_memory = int.Parse(logicstring);
                        free_memory.Text = remaining_memory.ToString();


                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("fan1on"))
                    {
                        fan1_status_light.Fill = greenBrush;
                        storyboard_fan1_led.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                        storyboard_fan1_led.Begin();
                        
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("fan1off"))
                    {
                        fan1_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                        storyboard_fan1_led.Stop();
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("fan2on"))
                    {
                        fan2_status_light.Fill = greenBrush;
                        storyboard_fan_2.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                        storyboard_fan_2.Begin();
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("fan2off"))
                    {
                        fan2_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                        storyboard_fan_2.Stop();
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorAON"))   //key
                    {
                        compressorA_status_light.Fill = greyBrush;
                        compressorAkey = 1;
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorAoff"))  //key
                    {
                        compressorA_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                        compressorAkey = 0;
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorBON"))  //key
                    {
                        compressorB_status_light.Fill = greyBrush;
                        compressorBkey = 1;
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorBoff")) //key
                    {
                        compressorB_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                        compressorBkey = 0;
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorA on")) // actually compressor on
                    {
                        compressorA_status_light.Fill = greenBrush;
                        storyboard_compA_Led.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                        storyboard_compA_Led.Begin();
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorB on")) // actually compressor on
                    {
                        compressorB_status_light.Fill = greenBrush;
                        storyboard_compB_led.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                        storyboard_compB_led.Begin();
                    }

                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressor off")) // actually compressor off
                    {
                        if (compressorBkey == 1)
                        {
                            compressorB_status_light.Fill = greyBrush;
                            storyboard_compB_led.Stop();
                        }
                        if (compressorAkey == 1)
                        {
                            compressorA_status_light.Fill = greyBrush;
                            storyboard_compA_Led.Stop();
                        }
                        if (compressorBkey == 0)
                        {
                            compressorB_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                            storyboard_compB_led.Stop();
                        }
                        if (compressorAkey == 0)
                        {
                            compressorA_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                            storyboard_compA_Led.Stop();
                        }
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorA off")) // actually compressor off
                    {
                        compressorA_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                        storyboard_compA_Led.Stop();
                    }
                    if (logicstring.StartsWith("compressorB off")) // actually compressor off
                    {
                        compressorB_status_light.Fill = redBrush;
                        storyboard_compB_led.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task WriteAsync(string text2write)
        {
            Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;

            if (text2write.Length != 0)
            {
                dataWriteObject.WriteString(text2write);

                storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask();  // Create a task object

                UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;   // Launch the task and wait
                if (bytesWritten > 0)
                {
                    //txtStatus.Text = bytesWritten + " bytes written at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
                }
            }
            else { }
        }


        private async Task sendToPort(string sometext)
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort != null)
                {
                    dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream);

                    await WriteAsync(sometext);
                }
                else { }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dataWriteObject != null)   // Cleanup once complete
                {
                    dataWriteObject.DetachStream();
                    dataWriteObject = null;
                }
            }
        }


        private void CancelReadTask()
        {
            if (ReadCancellationTokenSource != null)
            {
                if (!ReadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    ReadCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            }
        }
        
        private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CancelReadTask();
            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                serialPort.Dispose();
            }
            serialPort = null;
        }

        private async void init_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double sendtempvalue = (double)set_temperature.Value;
            if (serialPort == null) return;
            await sendToPort("settemp," + sendtempvalue);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EEPROM " + sendtempvalue);

            

        }

        private async void init_timing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double switching_time_minute = (double)set_switching_time.Value;
            if (serialPort == null) return;
            await sendToPort("switch_interval," + switching_time_minute);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EEPROM " + switching_time_minute);
        }

        

        /*
        private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst a good detailed question, I’m wondering if that’s a little too much code?   [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure you have a memory leak.  It’s quite common for .NET apps to ramp up then flatline memory use.   120MB doesn’t sound like much

Comment: Michael Xu's solution worked, the app doesn't consume more than 60MB even after using it for a long time, but it starts climbing above 100MB within 30 minutes if I choose to build the app using .net native tool chain

Comment: @NafisAhmedFahim, you may try to remove the CancellationToken in ReadAsync method.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: How do I modify the code to not change the uint
> ReadBufferLength = 1; and make the ReadAsync function store my serial
> incoming data until it finds \r\n ?

Please try to use following code. When using `ReadBufferLength = 1`, the transmission efficiency will be lower.

```
    private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 128;  // only when this buffer would be full next code would be executed

        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);   // Create a task object
        //string debug = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead2);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("writing string debug"+ debug);

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;    // Launch the task and wait until buffer would be full

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            strFromPort = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
            final_string = final_string + strFromPort;
            //txtStatus2.Text = final_string;
            if (final_string.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
            {
                string logicstring = final_string;
                final_string = final_string.Substring(final_string.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + 1);

                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("writing logic string " + logicstring);
                
            }
        }
    }
```

> Problem 2: after running it for 1 hour it will consume over 120
> megabytes whereas it starts at 30-50 megabytes initially.

Please try to build the app in release but not using the .NET native toolchain.It's a known issue. Please see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56ed40c8-a0b0-4fe4-a995-09c66675403a/memory-leak?forum=WindowsIoT).

> Problem 3: Cannot build the app in release mode using the option
> "Compile with .NET Native tool chain", without this it runs fine in
> the raspberry.

Please remove the references `runtime.win10-arm-aot.Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` and `runtime.win10-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` in your project. The project will be compiled with .Net native tool chain successfully without the two libraries, since that these two libs depends on the native lib of System.Runtime.InteropServices.